# How do I get only a determined number of words from a string in php?

Tags: php, string, function

Here is what I am trying to do.  I have a block of text and I would like to extract the first 50 words from the string without cutting off the words in the middle.  That is why I would prefer words opposed to characters, then I could just use a left() function.

I know the str_word_count($var) function will return the number of words in a string, but how would I return only the first 50 words?

I'm going full immersion on PHP and I'm not familiar with many of the string functions, yet.

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would recommend against using the number of words as a baseline. You could easily end up with *much* less or *much* more data than you intended to display.

One approach I've used in the past is to ask for a desired length, but make sure it does not truncate a word. Here's something that may work for you:

```
function function_that_shortens_text_but_doesnt_cutoff_words($text, $length)
{
    if(strlen($text) > $length) {
        $text = substr($text, 0, strpos($text, ' ', $length));
    }

    return $text;
}
```

That said, if you pass `1` as the second parameter to `str_word_count`, it will return an array containing all the words, and you can use array manipulation on that.
Also, you *could* although, it's somewhat hackey, explode the string on spaces, etc... But that introduces lots of room for error, such as things that are not words getting counted as words.

PS. If you need a Unicode safe version of the above function, and have either the `mbstring` or `iconv` extensions installed, simply replace all the string functions with their `mb_` or `iconv_` prefixed equivalents.

Comment: All the responses are quality, but you explained why I should go by characters instead of words.  Thanks!

Comment: By the way, you don't address the situation where there is no space in the first `$length` characters, and you can still end up with *much* less data than you intended to display if the only space is in the fourth character or so (see my answer for the solution).

Comment: Honestly, for what I've used this method for, that would never ever ever be an issue. Good point, though.

Answer (score 10):

str_word_count takes an optional parameter that tells it what to return.

Returns an array of strings that are the words:

```
$words = str_word_count($var, 1);
```

Then you can slice things up with something like:

```
$len = min(50, count($words));
$first_fifty = array_slice($words, 0, $len);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want a certain number of words? If you're doing something like a "preview", it's generally better to do something like "Up to 300 characters, cut off at a word boundary", in which case you can use something like:

```
if (strlen($str)>300)
{
  $str = substr($str,0,300);
  $pos = strrpos($str, ' ');
  if ($pos !== false && $pos > 200) // If there is no space in the last 100 chars, just truncate
    $str = substr($str,0,$pos);
  // You may also want to add ellipses:
  // $str .= '...';
}
```

Comment: Hi, whoever modded down my answer, could you explain what's wrong with it? I concede that it's not nearly as detailed as jason's answer, but I don't see anything wrong with it...

Comment: You got my vote up, but you forget what to do, if there is no space?

Comment: Actually, I addressed that situation. I've edited it to comment the specific line in which I do.

Answer (score 2):

I have found easier way to do this:

`function get_len_of_word($str,$number)
    {
       $array_str = explode(" ", $str);
       if(isset($array_str[$number]))
       {
         return implode(" ",array_slice($array_str, 0, $number));
       }
     return $str;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more example,

```
function getWordsFromString($str,$word_count)
{
    $new_str=$str;
    $_strArr=explode(" ",$str);
    $_tempArr=array();
    if(count($_strArr)>$word_count) 
    {
        foreach ($_strArr as $key=> $value) {
            $_tempArr[]=$value; 
            if($key==$word_count-1)
            {
                $new_str=implode(" ",$_tempArr).' ...';
            }
        }   
    }
    return $new_str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function get_first_num_of_words($string, $num_of_words)
    {
        $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($string));
        $words = explode(" ", $string); // an array

        // if number of words you want to get is greater than number of words in the string
        if ($num_of_words > count($words)) {
            // then use number of words in the string
            $num_of_words = count($words);
        }

        $new_string = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_of_words; $i++) {
            $new_string .= $words[$i] . " ";
        }

        return trim($new_string);
    }
```

Use it like this:

```
echo get_first_num_of_words("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, illo?", 5);
```

Output: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`

This function also works very well with unicode characters like Arabic characters.

```
echo get_first_num_of_words("نموذج لنص عربي الغرض منه توضيح كيف يمكن استخلاص أول عدد معين من الكلمات الموجودة فى نص معين.", 100);
```

Output: `نموذج لنص عربي الغرض منه توضيح كيف يمكن استخلاص أول عدد معين من الكلمات الموجودة فى نص معين.`