# Cut big sentence by PHP

Tags: php, string

```
$string = '"Above all," said British Prime Minister David Cameron, "what I think matters is building the evidence and the picture so we hold this criminal regime to account, and to make sure it is held to account for crimes that it is committing against its people." He spoke to reporters outside a meeting of leaders of the European Union in Brussels, Belgium.';
```

How do I cut this string to specified number of words? 5 or 10 for example.

And remove characters like `"&*$%>`. Some in-php function?

Should work for non-english languages too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get only a determined number of words from a string in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112946/how-do-i-get-only-a-determined-number-of-words-from-a-string-in-php)

Comment: Do you want to cut **this** string or **any** strings?

Comment: You will need to use `substr`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by cutting? Are you trying to output an array or are you trying to add i.e. some `<br/>` tag in between specified number of words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
// The number of words you want to keep
$numwords = 5;

// The symbols you want to have removed
$stripChars = array('"', '&', '*', '$', '%', '>');

$string = '"Above all," said British Prime Minister David Cameron, "what I think matters is building the evidence and the picture so we hold this criminal regime to account, and to make sure it is held to account for crimes that it is committing against its people." He spoke to reporters outside a meeting of leaders of the European Union in Brussels, Belgium.';

$string = str_replace($stripChars, '', $string);

$stringImpl = array_slice(explode(' ', $string, $numwords + 1), 0, $numwords);
$stringCleaned = implode(' ', $stringImpl);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this.  Not tested and could use some tinkering but it gives you the idea.

```
$num_words = 5;
$string = '"Above all," said British Prime Minister David Cameron, "what I think matters is building the evidence and the picture so we hold this criminal regime to account, and to make sure it is held to account for crimes that it is committing against its people." He spoke to reporters outside a meeting of leaders of the European Union in Brussels, Belgium.';
$string = preg_replace('/["&*$%>]/i', '', $string);
$words = explode(" ", $string);
$newstring = implode(" ", array_slice($words, 0, $num_words));
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the said characters you can do something along the lines of this:

```
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/&/';
$patterns[1] = '/%/';
$patterns[2] = '/>/';
preg_replace($patterns, '', $string);
```

Just add more items to the array if you want to remove more stuff.

To cut the string do this. Beware you may get a long output if you use words such as supercalifragilisticexpialidocious:

```
$newlen = 5; // change accordingly.
$stringarray = explode(' ', $string); // Explodes the string into an array. One item for each row.
$string = implode(' ', array_slice($stringarray, 0, $newlen)); // We then 'slice' the array, which basically cuts it. The 0 defines the starting point and the $newlen the end. After this we 'implode' it which basically converts it to a string. The ' ' shows what we want to stick in-between the items in the array.
```

Comment: This returnes the first 5 characters, but not words.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to split the string by number of words:

```
function substrwords($str, $n) {
    $words = explode(' ',$str);
    $outstr = '';
    for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
        $outstr .= $words[$i].' ';
    }
    return ltrim($outstr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to add i.e. the `<br/>` tag between desired number of words you can use a function here's an example (however I'm not satisfied with the function name)

```
function join_string($str, $word_count=5, $delimiter='<br/>') {
    $words = preg_split('/\s/',preg_replace('/["&*$%>]/','',$str));
    // splits each word
    $str = '';
    foreach ($words as $key => $value) {
        $i = $key % $word_count;
        if ($key > 0 && !$i) $str .= $delimiter;
        // adds the delimiter
        $str .= $value . ($i < $word_count-1 ? ' ' : '');
        // adds the space after the word
    }
    return $str;
}

echo join_string($string,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use substr

```
$string = '"Above all," said British Prime Minister David Cameron, "what I think matters is building the evidence and the picture so we hold this criminal regime to account, and to make sure it is held to account for crimes that it is committing against its people." He spoke to reporters outside a meeting of leaders of the European Union in Brussels, Belgium.';

//specify the number after which the string should be cut
$string_cut_position = 5;

$new_string = substr($string, 0, $string_cut_position);
```

To remove the special character like: `"&*$%>`

```
$new_string = preg_replace('/["&*$%>]/i', '', $new_string);
```

If you want to remove all Non-Alphanumeric Characters, then you could use

```
$new_string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $new_string );
```

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT:**

Sorry misread the question . i was thinking about cutting letters :(

You can try

```
//specify the number after which the string should be cut
$words_cut_position = 5;

$new_string = array_slice(explode(' ', $string, $words_cut_position + 1), 0, $words_cut_position);
$output_string  = implode(' ', $new_string);
```

Hope this helps :)..