# how to slice a big array into smaller ones

Tags: php, arrays, string

How do I slice a sentence of any length into arrays of say 5 words?

In other words:

```
$Dummy = "Here is  a long sentence, but what I need to make out of this sentence 
          is that it should be chunked off to smaller arrays with 5 words each."
```

I want the answer in PHP.

Thanks in advance for the one who solves it.

Comment: Please post your code so far, and explain what didn't work.

Comment: Not very sure with the requirement, but give a try with `explode()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How do I get only a determined number of words from a string in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1112946/367456) - and the many other ones. Please use the search.

Answer (score 7):

See [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

```
$words = str_word_count($sentence, 1);
$chunks = array_chunk($words, 5);
```

Comment: Wasn't expecting `str_word_count` to return the actual words....curious function.

Comment: instead of str_word_count, you can also use explode function. $words = explode(" ",$sentence);
str_word_count won't work with numeric characters, for example, if not explicitly specified and will consider them as delimiter.

Comment: @MuhammedHedayet well, `explode()` will leave empty elements for "double space". Everything has it's limitations. Also consider `array_filter()`.

Comment: Sorry guys I am new over here, I do not know much php. I can see the slicing part,  but now my problem is how to show these chunks, without the keys, print_r, returns the keys too. I need only values.

Comment: @SidSs: Well, you didn't *ask* about that, so please don't complain of not getting such un-asked questions unanswered. Also I bet you could be more successful finding an answer by using the search: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+cut+sentence+to+5+words+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=php+cut+sentence+to+5+words+site%3Astackoverflow.com&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 - Imagine with the more simple tasks that you're not the first person who wonders about - regardless of the skill-level of PHP.

Comment: You can iterate over the arrays using `foreach()`. These are basic things that you should lookup in the PHP docs